# how to create checkbox using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicontrol

Hey I want to create a checkbox in the screen, without using two different images with V and without. Does anyone know how I can do it? I didn't find UI class for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use a UIButton. Therefore having the V image will suffice. (Empty square image method is also explained)

The main method you need to call is:

```
//Set the 'V' image for UIControlStateSelected and [UIImage new] for UIControlStateNormal
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
        forState:(UIControlState)state; 



//Then, for the surrounding square box you can either use an image, OR better, use the borderWidth and borderColor property of the button's layer to achieve this effect.

//Image Method
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image
                  forState:(UIControlState)state; // Incase you use an image then, use the same image for both UIControlStateSelected and UIControlStateNormal.

//drawing method
[checkBoxButton.layer setBorderWidth:<Enter Width in CGFloat>];
[checkBoxButton.layer setBorderColor:<Enter Width in CGColor>];
```

NOTE: Here the crucial piece will be to maintain the selected state of the button by toggling the 'selected' property. The rest will take care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

That involves manually creating a UICheckbox which draws a 2D rectangle view and a custom view for the check.

So you will have to create your own UI element.